# Mac: Safari search history results are empty

Tags: mac, safari, bug

On Mac (Ventura 13.3.1) pressing ⌘Y, in Safari, to show-up search results, then filtering the results by searching, produces an empty result (no search results).
Even known, the site was actually visited.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: What were you expecting and what did you get?

Comment: So if I search for "Wikipedia", and I do have it there as an entry, I should see it. I get nothing instead.

Comment: Following your steps I can see I visited wikipedia (or any random site) several days ago so it's not a bug.  I'm on 13.3.1.

Comment: @fsb It behaves randomly on my side. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Could you please try it again some time?